# Real time browser game fight system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

recently I've been reading about JS, Ajax, jQuery and decided to write a system using those languages. First of all I want to do this for education and learning. So lets say there is a game and one of thing is fighting enemies and fight system is not "click" based. It goes like this:

1. Then opened a page code sends query to MySql and gets player information, like what kind of skill he has, hp, damage, etc.
2. Code creates buttons or images based on that how much skills player has
3. Every skill has it own cool-down
4. Code checks if left cool-down is 0 sec if yes activates button or image and lets user to press it if not then sets a timer below which shows how much time left till skill is usable again when timer hits 0 that button activates.
5. When some skill is used there is additional cool-down which adds to all skills and timer sets for all of em
6. When everything is ok and skill is used and stuff updates in mysql
7. Then all repeats till enemy or player dies
8. All this is happening real time

Well basically it is skill system like in PC games like silkroad, WOT, LOL and almost every mmorpg game.

I been trying to do this with Ajax, JS but I cant figure out best way to do it, keeping in mind that its fast and safe.

I am not asking for full code, just some info which function would be best to do this and how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Which function best to do what? The entire game? It's a whole lot of functions

Comment: This project sounds as a little too big for a learning exercise. Why don't you try to do something less challenging, like an online notes app. If you got the basics working, try adding more features (like logging in/being able to view your notes from wherever you are, rich text formatting, whatever). I think that is a lot more viable than a real-time, multiplayer, online game.

Comment: "can't figure out best way" - if you're really looking for the best way (and it's not an euphemism for "I have no clue"), then don't. Implement it in any way you know how. Then you'll be able to improve.

Comment: Better shipped than perfect :)

Comment: @11684 I said its learning exercise because I haven't done anything in PHP like in 2 years, I know more than enough at PHP and last 2 years c++ programming, but I haven't learned JS or any language like that earlier so decided to do something like this

Comment: @Glimber Still, without knowledge of front-end languages, this is a huge task.

Comment: @11684 Thats why I am doing this because it is challenging and takes effort to do it.

Comment: Q: How do you eat an elephant? A: One bite at a time. This is too much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this for the sake of advice.

I was once in your position, wanting to create the "coolest" game while having little to no experience. This is a difficult game to undertake, especially when you need to ask someone where to start in regard to code. My advice: master programming fundamentals and best practices. Watch tutorials and start with small projects. Otherwise I guarantee you'll end up with buggy, broken, spaghetti code.

1. **Learn basic JavaScript.** I prefer renting a physical book, but there's a million tutorials on the internet as well. Create fun, small projects to demonstrate understanding.
2. **Learn a server-side language** (like PHP). Start with making simple applications. Gain a strong understanding of client-server model. Once you get the hang of it, start refining your database skills, in MySQL or something similar. (hint, this is a way to store your game data).
3. **Learn jQuery and AJAX**. Not to be repetitive, but keep learning. Take on tasks that challenge but don't overwhelm. Learn how to manipulate the DOM and communicate between the client and server with AJAX. This is all tied together.
4. **Learn Node.js and Socket.io**. This is just a suggestion. Both of these libraries are great for building real-time games. But you will not understand these packages without mastering the basics listed above. They are both in JavaScript. There's a great chat tutorial on the Socket.io website to start with.
5. **Finish a game before you start a new one**. Don't be like me and take on projects way too large. Start small, not all games have to be giant with amazing graphics to be fun. And unless it's a complete disaster, don't scrap all of your code to get a fresh start. Have a plan and stick to it.

In summary, master core concepts before taking on something too difficult.

EDIT: I just read your comment about you having knowledge in PHP and C++. But I'm not going to alter my answer. With no offense intended, a seasoned programmer would not ask such a "noob" question. Hit the books/tutorials, and in the future ask specific, high quality questions, after putting effort into finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a real-time game in Javascript using only AJAX. You will need to turn yourself to sockets.

Sockets are basically a two-way persistent connection : when you make an http request, you open the request, servers responds you, you close the request. This makes it difficult in order to build a real-time application, as server can't push data to you without an opened request. Sockets keeps an existing connection between you and the server, so it's like a persistent canal between you and the server.

You can check Node.js, which fits perfectly for this use of sockets.
For your others questions, I suggest you to search a little more by yourself ;)